# elasticsearch - Return the tokens of a field

Tags: java, search, lucene, token, elasticsearch

How can I have the tokens of a particular field returned in the result

For example, A GET request

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1'
```

returns

```
{
    "_index" : "twitter",
    "_type" : "tweet",
    "_id" : "1", 
    "_source" : {
        "user" : "kimchy",
        "postDate" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
        "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
    } 
}
```

I would like to have the tokens of '_source.message' field included in the result

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is also another way to do it using the following script_fields script:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/test-idx/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "message"
            }
        }

    }
}'
```

It's important to note that while this script returns the actual terms that were indexed, it also caches all field values and on large indices can use a lot of memory. So, on large indices, it might be more useful to retrieve field values from stored fields or source and reparse them again on the fly using the following MVEL script:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import java.io.StringReader;

// Cache analyzer for further use
cachedAnalyzer=(isdef cachedAnalyzer)?cachedAnalyzer:doc.mapperService().documentMapper(doc._type.value).mappers().indexAnalyzer();

terms=[];
// Get value from Fields Lookup
//val=_fields[field].values;

// Get value from Source Lookup
val=_source[field];

if(val != null) {
  tokenStream=cachedAnalyzer.tokenStream(field, new StringReader(val)); 
  CharTermAttribute termAttribute = tokenStream.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute); 
  while(tokenStream.incrementToken()) { 
    terms.add(termAttribute.toString())
  }; 
  tokenStream.close(); 
} 
terms
```

This MVEL script can be stored as `config/scripts/analyze.mvel` and used with the following query:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/test-idx/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "analyze",
            "params": {
                "field": "message"
            }
        }
    
    }
}'
```

Comment: It is scary, but fun. :) I wish it was possible to access IndexReader in DocLookup (it's there, but it's private at the moment). Then it would have been possible to use term vectors instead of re-analyzing the text the second time.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Wouldn't it be nice also to read the term vectors without scripts, maybe through a plugin?

Comment: @imotov is there any way of getting the correct analyzer and field type for a field automatically from this script? I'd like to use this functionality in https://metacpan.org/module/Elastic::Model::Role::Doc#terms_indexed_for_field-

Comment: Very good answer, thanks. Maybe it'd be useful to pluginize it?

Comment: Please add tokenStream.reset(); before while cycle (otherwise it fails on my setup).

Comment: I don't think this is possible to achieve without writing a plugin in elasticsearch 5.0 and above.

Answer (score 7):

If you mean the tokens that have been indexed you can make a [terms facet](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/facets.html) on the message field. Increase the `size` value in order to get more entries back, or set to `0` to get all terms.

Lucene provides the ability to store the term vectors, but there's no way to have access to it with elasticsearch by now (as far as I know).

Why do you need that? If you only want to check what you're indexing you can have a look at the [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays, it's possible with the [Term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-termvectors.html):

```
curl http://localhost:9200/twitter/_termvectors/1?fields=message
```

Result:

```
{
  "_index": "twitter",
  "_id": "1",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "took": 0,
  "term_vectors": {
    "message": {
      "field_statistics": {
        "sum_doc_freq": 4,
        "doc_count": 1,
        "sum_ttf": 4
      },
      "terms": {
        "elastic": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 2,
              "start_offset": 11,
              "end_offset": 18
            }
          ]
        },
        "out": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 1,
              "start_offset": 7,
              "end_offset": 10
            }
          ]
        },
        "search": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 3,
              "start_offset": 19,
              "end_offset": 25
            }
          ]
        },
        "trying": {
          "term_freq": 1,
          "tokens": [
            {
              "position": 0,
              "start_offset": 0,
              "end_offset": 6
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: Mapping types (here: tweets) have been removed in Elasticsearch 8.x (see [migration guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed)).