# ElasticSearch return multi_field field value in query response

Tags: elasticsearch

My question is how to return the tokens of the `sub-field` of a `multi_field` when doing a query. I only seem to be able to get the value of the `multi_field` itself, not the analyzed token value.

I have a `multi_field` setup on my url field to split out the file extension (if any). This creates the following mapping:

```
{
  "url": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
      "ext": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "url_ext_analyzer",
        "include_in_all": false
      },
      "untouched": {
        "type": "string",
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "index_options": "docs",
        "include_in_all": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my test query, I'm trying to make the `url.ext` field value return in the response by doing this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "filter": {
    "term": {
      "url.ext": "pdf"
    }
  },
  "fields": [
    "_id",
    "_type",
    "url",
    "title",
    "url.ext"
  ]
}
```

But it doesn't show up in the response. (The other fields I've asked for do show up in the fields array):

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "test2",
      "_type": "doc",
      "_id": "1",
      "_score": 1,
      "fields": {
        "url": "http://bacon.com/static/764612436137067/cms/documents/bacon-ipsum.pdf",
        "title": "Bacon ipsum"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

bash script to create example:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/test2?pretty
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test2?pretty -d '{
  "index": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "myFileExtRegex": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": "(.*)\\.([a-z]{3,5})$",
          "replacement": "$2"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "url_ext_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [
            "myFileExtRegex"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test2/doc/_mapping?pretty -d '{
  "tweet": {
    "index_analyzer": "standard",
    "search_analyzer": "standard",
    "date_formats": [
      "yyyy-MM-dd",
      "dd-MM-yyyy"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "content": {
        "type": "string",
        "analyzer": "standard"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
          "untouched": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
          "ext": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "url_ext_analyzer",
            "stored": "yes"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'

curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/test2/doc/1?pretty' -d '{
  "content": "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ham drumstick jowl ham hock capicola meatball shankle pork filet mignon ground round jerky turkey prosciutto",
  "title": "Bacon ipsum",
  "url": "http://bacon.com/static/764612436137067/cms/documents/bacon-ipsum.pdf"
}'

curl -XGET localhost:9200/test2/_mapping?pretty
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mapping, you should have `"store" : "yes"` instead of `"stored": "yes"`. Simple typo.

I'm not positive your Regex is working as expected, but returning the field in a search request is solved by fixing the typo. You will notice that both the `"url"` and `"url.ext"` fields return the same thing, which sounds like it might not be what you want, but I'm not sure.

Here is a runnable example. I added `"store" : "yes"` to both `url` sub-fields, and added a couple of facets to the search request so you can see what the tokens are for the `url` sub-fields. I also changed `"tweet"` to `"doc"` in the mapping, which seems to be what you meant.

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/60c448df41827146e93daf0a93591f001d46e42f

Comment: Fixing the typo does help, but you're right it returns the same value for url and url.ext (the full URL). Is there a way to make it return the analyzed value for the hit? (The facets return the all the terms in the index e.g. pdf, xslx, docx and don't correspond to a particular hit)

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178550/elasticsearch-return-the-tokens-of-a-field

Comment: And here is an updated example: http://sense.qbox.io/gist/941f2b944829e5f648a698a4b5922e4617d2f8b0