# ElasticSearch and special characters

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I can not figure out how to look up words with special characters.

For example, I have two documents:

1) We are looking for C++ and C# developers 
2) We are looking for C developers

I want only to find a document which contains `C++`.

Code for creating an index, documents and searching:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch.helpers import scan

ELASTIC_SEARCH_NODES = ['http://localhost:9200']

INDEX = 'my_index'
DOC_TYPE = 'material'


def create_index():
    data = {
       "settings": {
          "analysis": {
             "analyzer": {
                "my_analyzer": {
                   "type": "custom",
                   "filter": [
                      "lowercase"
                   ],
                   "tokenizer": "whitespace",
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }

    print es_client.indices.create(index=INDEX, body=data)


def create_doc(body):

    if es_client.exists(INDEX, DOC_TYPE, body['docid']):
        es_client.delete(INDEX, DOC_TYPE, body['docid'])

    print es_client.create(index=INDEX, doc_type=DOC_TYPE, body=body, id=body['docid'])


def find_doc(value):
     results_generator = scan(es_client,
            query={"query": {

                    "match_phrase" : {
                        "text" : value
                    }

            }},
            index=INDEX
        )
     return results_generator


if __name__ == '__main__':
    es_client = Elasticsearch(ELASTIC_SEARCH_NODES, verify_certs=True)

    # create_index()
    doc1 = {"docid": 1, 'text': u"We are looking for C developers"}
    doc2 = {"docid": 2, 'text': u"We are looking for C++ and C# developers"}

    # create_doc(doc1)
    # create_doc(doc2)

    for r in find_doc("C++"):
        print r
```

Search result(if I [escape](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters) `+` (`"C\+\+"`), the result will be the same):

```
{u'_score': 0.0, u'_type': u'material', u'_id': u'2', u'_source': {u'text': u'We are looking for C++ and C# developers', u'docid': 2}, u'_index': u'my_index'}
{u'_score': 0.0, u'_type': u'material', u'_id': u'1', u'_source': {u'text': u'We are looking for C developers', u'docid': 1}, u'_index': u'my_index'}
```

It seems that such a result is obtained because in the division into tokens symbols like `+` and `#` [not indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13178550/elasticsearch-return-the-tokens-of-a-field), and in fact, it looks for documents in which there is the symbol `C`:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/my_index/material/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
    },
    "script_fields": {
        "terms" : {
            "script": "doc[field].values",
            "params": {
                "field": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Result:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "material",
      "_id" : "2",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "terms" : [ "and", "are", "c", "developers", "for", "looking", "we" ]
      }
    }, {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "material",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "fields" : {
        "terms" : [ "are", "c", "developers", "for", "looking", "we" ]
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

How can this problem be solved? The second question related to the previous: is it possible to search only non-alphanumeric characters such as `%` or `+` ?

P.S. I am using Elastic 2.3.2 and elasticsearch=2.3.0.

Comment: i mean, it's kinda obvious, yes, it was indexed that way to omit ++ and #, and of course later on you will be able to find both of them. I'm not sure if i get all python code, but it looks like you didn't set up your analyzer to work against your field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Andrew](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551949/181420), I solved the problem. The problem was that the standard analyzer was used for indexing, and not *my_analyzer*. Thus, I forgot to use the mapping. The correct version:

```
data = {
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "my_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase"
               ],
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
       "material": {
           "properties": {
               "docid": {
                   "type": "integer"
               },
               "text": {
                   "type": "string",
                   "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

In addition, it was necessary to recreate the index and add documents.
To search for special characters, you I am using the [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html). Code of `find_doc` function:

```
def find_doc(value):
     results_generator = scan(es_client,
            query=
            {
                "query": {
                    "filtered" : {
                        "query" : {
                            "query_string" : {
                                "query": value,
                                "fields" : ["text"],
                                "analyzer": ANALYZER,
                                "default_operator": "AND"
                            },

                        }
                    }

                }
            },
            index=INDEX
        )
     return results_generator
```

Examples of queries (now the [wildcard-characters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) can be used):

```
for r in find_doc("*#"):
    print r

for r in find_doc(u"%"):
    print r

for r in find_doc("looking fo*"):
    print r
```

Request for verification of the analyzer (on which token string is broken):

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_analyzer&pretty=true" -d 'We are looking for C++ and C# developers'
```